# Third person camera flips on loop

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

```
    float FoV = initialFoV - 5;
//(*it)->getParent()->getPosition() + (*it)->getOrientationQuat() * (*it)->getPosition();
glm::vec3 lookAt = carPosition;

glm::vec3 temp;

temp.x = spaceShip->orientation.y;
temp.y = spaceShip->orientation.x;
temp.z = spaceShip->orientation.z;

glm::vec3 cameraposition = carPosition + glm::quat(temp) * position;

ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(FoV, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);



ViewMatrix       = glm::lookAt(
                            cameraposition,     // Camera is here
                            lookAt,                                     // and looks here : at the same position, plus "direction"
                            vec3(0, 1, 0)                               // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                       );
```

As you can see we build a third person camera, this camera is chasing our airplane. But when our airplane makes a looping, the camera will flip halfway through. So everything is upside down. How can we make sure the camera won't flip?

Comment: It seems you are constraining your camera to always "be up". See lookAt call. When you airplane does a loop, at some point, it is upside down. Your camera will flip (not the ariplane) to "stay up". Cannot tell more as I cannot test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by calculating the up instead of setting it.

```
glm::vec3 cameraposition = carPosition + glm::quat(temp) * position;
ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(FoV, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 RotationMatrix        = eulerAngleYXZ(carDirection.x, carDirection.y, carDirection.z);
glm::vec4 up = RotationMatrix * glm::vec4(0,1,0,0);
glm::vec3 up3(up);

ViewMatrix       = glm::lookAt(
                            cameraposition,     // Camera is here
                            lookAt,                                     // and looks here : at the same position, plus "direction"
                            up3                             // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                       );
```

Comment: If your camera is fixed with respect to the airplane, wouldn't it be easier to simple take the matrix of the airplane and add some offset to find the matrix of the camera? (instead of using lookAt?)